# Google Maps View not showing on phone

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

When I try `[self.view addSubview:mapView];`, nothing will show up on either my phone or the Xcode simulator.

I just get a blank white screen. That being said, when I do `self.view = mapView;`, it works on the Xcode simulator, but causes a `BAD_ACCESS` error on my phone.

To be more specific, I declare `GMSMapView *mapView;` in the header file, and in the implementation file I do:

```
mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
mapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;
self.view = mapView;
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you have problem with allocation function. You can try using MKMapView (with MapKit.framework) instead GMSMapView.

Answer (score 0):

I am suspicious that you posted both the lines `self.view = mapView;` and `[self.view addSubview:mapView];` — although how these fit together isn’t clear from the information provided.

However, trying to add a view as a subview of itself results in a clear exception, rather than `BAD_ACCESS`.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I was initializing the view with `CGRectZero` rather than `self.view.frame`.